# return list of filtered products from woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I need to make a custom query returns all products fits my query with all their images, meta and all "advanced custom fields" acf for each product in **json** format.

I partially succeed using the following code:

```
function get_woocommerce_product_list($request) {
    $query = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_vendor',
                'value' => 'farsi',
            ),
        )
    );

    $result = [];
    $wp_query =  new WP_Query($query);

    foreach ($wp_query->posts as $post) {
        $result[$post->ID]['product'] = $post;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the top part of the code is fine, i'd change the code below to something like:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $query );
$result = array();

if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {

while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
$wp_query->the_post();

  $result[] = array(
   'product_name' => get_the_title(),
   'price' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true ),
   //find rest of values you require and put them into the array here
 );

 }
}

$json_result = json_encode($result);
return $json_result;
```